# Selenium Locating Unclickable Element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to locate a element, but I can't click on it. The id is ("save-all-conditionally"), but it's not working if I click on it. I tried `css.selector`, `xpath` and all other things, but nothing is working!

[image: Webiste picture]

Comment: share the url and explain what is the information you want to extract from the page.

Comment: The URL is https://www.gmx.net/ and if you visit the website for the first time you have to accept the cookies. (Picture) 
I just want to click on the Accept Button (Green)

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Also post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 2 frames, frame inside frame.
> You would need to switch to parent frame then child frame.
> here is the working code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.gmx.net/consent-management/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
firstFrame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='permission-core-iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(firstFrame)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='save-all-conditionally']").click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working :) <3

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, see if it works:

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='save-all-conditionally']")
ele.click()
```

Comment: Not working for me :(

Answer (score -1):

Not tested yet:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
if len(iframe) == 1:
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe[0])
    button = driver.find_element_by_id('save-all-conditionally')
    if button:
        button.click()
```

Since the iframe has no id get it by tag name, it should be one iframe use `switch_to.frame` to switch to the iframe content and get the button to click on it

Comment: sorry but its not working. is it working for you?

Comment: I have not tested with that site but that's how to click a button, since the button has id it should be easy

Comment: yeah i know, but unfortunately not

Comment: This approach does not work with Selenium, never has. What happens is if the element doesn't exist, the first line throws an Exception and never gets to the second line. If you are trying to test if an element exists (which has nothing to do with this question), the way to do it is to use, `button = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'save-all-conditionally') if button: button[0].click()`.

Comment: I think the problem is that the button is inside an iframe

Comment: @user16822867 but is it possible to click it?

Comment: see the edit and test it, not tested with that site